# How to set a large param in URL link for Oracle Apex Charts? (or any alternative)

Tags: oracle, charts, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I've built a dashboard with some pie charts. I also got to implement a drill down based on what region of a chart you select.

I set the following in Chart/Attributes/Link/Target (setting link Type: Redirect to URL)

Type: URL

URL: `javascript:clickChart_1_6_7_8("#ID_POLIZAS#")`

Of course ID_POLIZAS is a column name from data selected in the chart query. This field can be really long, it is selected as a CLOB value in the query.

But it looks like Oracle Apex doesn't allow to set that large URLs. It's throwing an ORA-06502 on runtime:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

Other charts are working properly, it only happens on charts with a lot of data on ID_POLIZAS column.

Is there a way to pass that kind of value to a javascript function when clicking on a chart region?

Comment: you said `it is selected as a CLOB value in the query` . What is the data type of the field in the table ?? is it really a CLOB ??

Comment: It's not a field from the database table, it's buit like this:

`rtrim(xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(e,P.IDEPOL,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ).GetClobVal(), ',') AS ID_POLIZAS`

It takes the ID of matching records in a group and makes a large text with those IDs separated by comma.

Comment: SC, can you provide a reproducible case ?

Comment: Perhaps you should adjust your logic to select a numeric identifier instead of a CLOB. There's probably middle tier restrictions on HTML parameter sizes.

Comment: Yes, @Scott, that's what I supposed, but retrieved data can be really long, so I can't select it as a numeric field. The retrieved data looks like `124567,1234566,1234565...` and may include thousands of comma separated values, that's why I fetch it as a CLOB type.